# How to add colour to a histplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, seaborn, histogram

This is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np 

plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
ax=sns.histplot(x='type',data=df[df.isFraud == 1],stat='percent',multiple='dodge',common_norm=False,bins=25)
ax=sns.histplot(x='type',data=df[df.isFraud == 0],stat='percent',multiple='dodge',common_norm=False,bins=25)
ax.set_ylabel('Percentage in Each Type')
ax.set_xlabel('Transaction Amount')
plt.legend(labels=['Fraud', 'Not Fraud'])
plt.show()
```

This is the output [image: Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2et9z.jpg)

I need different colours for 'fraud' and 'not fraud'

I tried adding the colour and palette parameter according to the documentation but it's not working out. I think its getting overridden by some other thing but i am not sure what it is.

I am working on a dataframe from kaggle. I want to show the correlation between the column [isFraud 0 or 1] and the types of transactions. I have edited the post and added a sample of the dataframe.

here is a screenshot of the dataframe [image: dataframe]

Comment: Could show some examples of your data?

Comment: @JayPeerachai I am working on a dataframe from kaggle. I want to show the correlation between the column [isFraud 0 or 1] and the types of transactions. I have edited the post and added a sample of the dataframe.

Comment: Have you tried the hue parameter?

`ax = sns.histplot(x='type', hue='isFraud', data=df, stat='percent', multiple='dodge', common_norm=False, bins=25)`

Comment: @amur Yes. Doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I replicated your code with the `tips` dataset of seaborn. Try to use the `color` parameter of `histplot` the same as below.

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('tips')

plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
ax=sns.histplot(x='time',data=df[df.smoker == "Yes"],stat='percent',multiple='dodge',common_norm=False,bins=25, color='b')
ax=sns.histplot(x='time',data=df[df.smoker == "No"],stat='percent',multiple='dodge',common_norm=False,bins=25, color='r')
ax.set_ylabel('/')
ax.set_xlabel('Time')
plt.legend(labels=['Smoker', 'Not smoker'])
plt.show()
```

[Here is the output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DHAJ.png)

Comment: Did it. But this is what it shows me https://imgur.com/17yzu9g.jpg I'm hoping for my histogram to look something like this. https://imgur.com/stN6s1v.jpg